# Crear separadores en graficas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Cree un gráfico en C# que cada segundo se van añadiendo mas datos, se hizo con Windows forms en C#.

[image: Gráfica]

Quisiera poder añadirle una marca, una línea que marque un segundo que yo con un botón le indique, parecido al separador de los libros que es una marca de donde se estaba leyendo. Yo quiero añadir una o varias según sea necesario.

Así se vería el gráfico con las marcas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias

Comment: Hola Juan, ¿puedes capturar la pantalla en lugar de tomar fotos?

Comment: vas a tener que agregar el codigo relevante, que tipo de objetos estas usando y mas informacion, como por ejemplo de que forma queres agregar la marca.. haciendo click? ingresandolo en un textbox?? un combo??